# Difference Between Matlabs classify and ClassificationDiscriminant functions

Tags: classification, matlab

I recently came upon a discrepancy between Matlab's classify and ClassificationDiscriminant functions. By default, they should both be doing Linear DiscriminantAnalysis, but when given unbalanced classes, they give very different results.

I have created a small test script [here at Gist](https://gist.github.com/dvreed77/4980426) which creates some data that is unbalanced but easily separable. I test my classifiers on the training data for optimal results. For a linear classifier, the result should be unique, but it appears this is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two functions do slightly different things.

According to the docs, `classify` uses a uniform prior (i.e., each class is equally likely). On the other hand, it looks `ClassificationDiscriminant` uses an empirical prior (i.e., the proportions of each class in your training data).

To extend your example on Gist:

```
N1 = 3500; N2 = 1500;
data = [randn(N1, 1) ; 1 + randn(N2, 1)];
labels = [zeros(N1, 1) ; ones(N2, 1)];

y_pred = classify(data, data, labels);
TP1 = sum(y_pred == 1 & labels == 1); %TP1 is now 1033

temp = ClassificationDiscriminant.fit(data, labels);
y_pred2 = temp.predict(data);
TP2 = sum(y_pred2 == 1 & labels == 1); %TP2 is 582
```

If you want them to match, you have two options. You could force ClassificationDiscriminant to use a uniform prior, like so:

```
temp.Prior = [0.5 0.5]
y_pred2 = temp.predict(data);
TP2 = sum(y_pred2 == 1 & labels == 1); %TP2 is now 1033, matching TP1
```

Alternately, you could provide the empirical prior to the classify function, like this:

```
y_pred = classify(data, data, labels, 'linear', [N1 N2]./(N1+N2));
TP1 = sum(y_pred == 1 & labels == 1); %TP1 is now 582
```

You could also pass the string 'empirical' as the last argument to `classify` for the same effect. Here are links to the relevant documentation:

- [classify @ MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classify.html)
- [ClassificationDiscriminant class @ MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classificationdiscriminantclass.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I was looking through the docs, but must have missed this vital detail.

Comment: Glad I could help! It's a subtle gotcha and I sometimes wish The Mathworks were a little more consistent about everything.